# Demonstrating a field extension is not Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

Let, $\alpha \ne 1$ be the root of $x^{11}- 1$. The automorphism group of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ consists of $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_{10} \}$ such that: $\phi_{j} = x^j$ for $j \in [1,10]$. We wish to demonstrate that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not Galois. We have that, $\alpha$ is the root of $x^{11} - 1$, and $x^{11}-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$; hence, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ which then implies $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is an algebraic extension; however,
$$\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q^{k} = q, \forall k \in [1,10] \}  = \{1\} \ne \mathbb{Q},$$
this means the field fixed by the automorphism group is not equal to $\mathbb{Q}$; hence, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ cannot be Galois. Any mistakes, does this look right? Thanks!

Comment: The field is [very] Galois. Your misunderstanding of the $\phi_j$ is messing you up. $\phi_j(x)=x^j$ holds true for any of the $11$-roots of unity - not for every element of the field. For another example, take $K=\mathbb Q (\beta)$, where $\beta^2 =2$. Then $K$ over the rationals is Galois, with group of order 2, the non-trivial element $\sigma$ of which takes $\beta \mapsto -\beta$. However, $\sigma$ does not act by multiplication by $-1$ on $K$. Instead,  $\sigma:x + y\beta \mapsto x-y\beta$, where  $x,y$ rationals.  Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW, $\alpha$ is 'a' root $\not=1$, not 'the' root $\not=1$.

Comment: @peterag, I see thank you.